# Loop over 2 pandas Dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like the following:

[image]

How can I loop over `flow.id` and `kit.id` simultaneously to feed values into a query?

I tried making another column `Rate` like the following:

```
 df['Rate'][i] = FlowKits.objects.filter(kit__id = df['kit.id'][i], flow__id = df['flow.id'][i]).values("trip_cost")
```

Bur got the `Keyerror`

> KeyError: 'Rate'

How should I do it ?

Sample data:

```
obj     kit.id  flow.id
0       18       10
1       19       12
2       18       10
3       19       12
4       19       12
```

Comment: Can you share sample data?

Comment: use [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) if you want to loop over rows something like `df.apply(lambda row:row['column'],axis=1)` For more pro use you can use numpy..